# How to bind LIKE values using the PDO extension?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, bindparam

In this query

```
select wrd from tablename WHERE wrd LIKE '$partial%'
```

I'm trying to bind the variable `'$partial%'` with PDO. Not sure how this works with the `%` at the end.

Would it be

```
select wrd from tablename WHERE wrd LIKE ':partial%'
```

where `:partial` is bound to `$partial="somet"`

or would it be

```
select wrd from tablename WHERE wrd LIKE ':partial'
```

where `:partial` is bound to `$partial="somet%"`

or would it be something entirely different?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You could also say:

```
SELECT wrd FROM tablename WHERE wrd LIKE CONCAT(:partial, '%')
```

to do the string joining at the MySQL end, not that there's any particular reason to in this case.

Things get a bit more tricky if the partial `wrd` you are looking for can itself contain a percent or underscore character (since those have special meaning for the LIKE operator) or a backslash (which MySQL uses as another layer of escaping in the LIKE operator — incorrectly, according to the ANSI SQL standard).

Hopefully that doesn't affect you, but if you do need to get that case right, here's the messy solution:

```
$stmt= $db->prepare("SELECT wrd FROM tablename WHERE wrd LIKE :term ESCAPE '+'");
$escaped= str_replace(array('+', '%', '_'), array('++', '+%', '+_'), $var);
$stmt->bindParam(':term', $escaped);
```

Comment: To escape or not to escape ... It depends on the intent of the character. Was it's intent to be a wildcard or a literal? I wouldn't expect a prepared statement to decide this for me. It's job is to escape characters in the value that would terminate the `LIKE` clause and inject unwanted sql.

Comment: +1 for the 'messy' solution. The only time I wouldn't use it is if I wanted to give my users the ability to put wildcards in their own search string.

Comment: I would like to add a note why the str_replace does not cycle - `Because str_replace() replaces left to right` so first, the `+` gets escaped, then `%` and in the end the `_` ... so no +++++++++  :-)

Answer (score 19):

```
$var = "partial%";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("select wrd from tablename WHERE wrd LIKE :partial");
$stmt->bindParam(":partial", $var);
$stmt->execute(); // or $stmt->execute(array(':partial' => $var)); without 
                  // first calling bindParam()
$rs = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Using question mark parameters:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('select wrd from tablename WHERE wrd LIKE ?');
$stmt->execute(array('partial%'));
$rs = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use addcslashes before prepared statement. I tested on mysql.

```
$value = addcslashes($value, '%');
$stmt = $db->prepare('select * from products where description like ?');
$stmt->execute(["$value%"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the accepted answer (by @bobince) can be simplified a bit.

You can reduce it to something like this to handle underscore, percentage, etc in the param but still match the LIKE query with partial%:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("select wrd from tablename WHERE wrd LIKE :partial");
$stmt->execute([":partial" => addcslashes($value, '_%') . "%"]);
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how you should do it

```
bindValue(':partial', '%' . $_GET['partial'] . '%');
```

Thanks,

Qwerty

Comment: This is such an incredibly bad idea.

Comment: @acoder without an explanation your comment isn't helpful.

Comment: Even with abstraction, using a raw unfiltered _GET value in a query sounds like a really bad time waiting to happen.

Answer (score -1):

The below code it shows only the first keywords in the database!

```
"SELECT wrd FROM tablename WHERE wrd LIKE CONCAT(:partial, '%')"
```

Try this one if you want to search all the keywords from the database

```
"SELECT wrd FROM tablename WHERE wrd LIKE :partial";
$stmt->execute(array(':partial'=>'%'.$YourVarHere.'%'));
```

Answer (score -4):

Who has written the answare (may be karim79):

> ```
> $var ="partial%"
> $stmt =$dbh->prepare("select wrd from tablename WHERE wrd LIKE :partial")
> $stmt->bindParam(":partial",$var)
> $stmt->execute(); //or$stmt->execute(array(':partial'=>$var)); without 
>                   // first calling bindParam()
> $rs =$stmt->fetchAll();
> ```
>
> Using question mark parameters:
>
> ```
> $stmt =$dbh->prepare('select wrd from tablename WHERE wrd LIKE ?');
> $stmt->execute(array('partial%'));
> $rs =$stmt->fetchAll();
> ```

Many thanks to him. I was searching for the code & saw many examples, but i couldn't resolve my issue. This time I have succeed to do it. I used the 'Using question mark parameters:' section of the code.

For others help, if you want to retrieve the value from a variable you may change the code to

```
$stmt->execute(array($variable.'%'));
```

instead of

```
$stmt->execute(array('partial%'));
```

Because the word 'partial' is specified in the answer and can't be changed. Thanks a lot.