# how to fix pdo mysql query for search?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("select * from article where concat_ws(' ',title,text)
                      like :search order by rank");
$stmt->bindValue(':search','%'.$data.'%'); 
$stmt->execute();
```

This search query doesn't work properly.is it correct the way i
passing value to the query? i means binding part.if there is another
way to do that give me that advice also.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722136/mysql-pdo-how-to-bind-like

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql PDO how to bind LIKE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722136/mysql-pdo-how-to-bind-like)