# PHP PDO query not executing

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm trying to build a search function for my database but it's not returning any results. This is what I got:

```
$searchQuery = $_GET[q];
$search = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM articles WHERE title LIKE \'%:query%\' OR content LIKE \'%:query%\'');
$search->bindParam(':query', $searchQuery, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$search->execute();
$searchResult = $search->fetchAll();

foreach($searchResult as $row) {
    print "<h2><a href=\"view.php?a=" . $row[id] . "\">" . $row[title] . "</a></h2>";
}
```

When I execute the SQL statement directly with `$conn->query('SELECT...')` it works perfectly, but not with the prepared statement. I don't get an error, it just doesn't load any results. What am I missing?

Edit: moved the wildcards from the prepared statements to the bind variable like this:

```
$searchQuery = '%' . $_GET[q] . '%';
$search = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM articles WHERE title LIKE :query OR content LIKE :query');
```

Works perfectly now. Thank you!

Comment: In short: do not quote your parameters. Pass the wildcards in with your bindParam, not in the query itself.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think you meant [Using bind parameters with LIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722136/mysql-pdo-how-to-bind-like)

Comment: You also need unique placeholders. Also, might want to look at full text indexing.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: @GolezTrol I added that one (dupe) now, thanks. This on top of the quotes in `\'%:query%\'`.

Comment: You actually need the quotes for the `%` (or add them in the bind parameter, I guess?). The misconception is that you can use parameters inside a SQL string