# MySQL LIKE operator in PHP

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I should execute this method, 
but I don't know how pass %research value as LIKE parameter in bind:

```
public function researchElements($research) {
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM product WHERE product_name LIKE "'%?%'"");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $research);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $result = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722136/mysql-pdo-how-to-bind-like) help?

Answer (score 1):

At least you can use in your query `CONCAT` function like next:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM product WHERE product_name LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%')");
```

Note: if `$research` variable gets value `''`, then query will return all rows from the table.